# MySQL Subquery Select very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

One of our websites has a table with about 60'000 records in it. Recently we noticed the page was timing out and could only be resolved by setting the memory limit to -1. This allowed the page to load but it was very slow. Furthermore I did not believe this was the correct way to resolve the problem, as obviously it indicates something is not quite right.

I managed to output the query that the page was running:

```
SELECT u.*,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enquiry e WHERE e.user_id = u.id AND e.deleted = 0 AND e.time_started != 0) AS opened_count,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enquiry e WHERE e.user_id = u.id AND e.deleted = 0 AND e.confirmed = 1 AND e.time_started != 0) AS confirmed_count,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enquiry e WHERE e.user_id = u.id AND e.deleted = 0 AND e.call_back = 1 AND e.time_started != 0) AS call_back_count
FROM user u
WHERE u.active = 1 AND u.deleted = 0
ORDER BY u.username
```

I ran this query in phpMyAdmin and it takes over 30 seconds to return the results.

I feel the query needs optimising in some way but I'm struggling to work out how. I'm guessing I need to use a JOIN of some sort?

Comment: Please provide the `EXPLAIN` as well as `DESCRIBE` results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're really running >180,000 queries, since each of those 3 subqueries will be run once for every row in the user table.

You could try simplifying into a standard join with some groups, e.g.

```
SELECT user.*,
    COUNT(enq.id) AS opened_count
    SUM(e.confirmed = 1) AS confirmed_count
    SUM(e.call_back = 1) AS call_back_count
FROM user
LEFT JOIN  enquiry ON enquiry.user_id = user.id
WHERE user.active = 1 and user.deleted AND enquiry.deleted = 0
GROUP BY user.id
```

Comment: Doesn't this need a group by?

Comment: Thanks Marc. That has already made a massive difference. One small thing I need help with - how do I integrate my WHERE condition in to the COUNT query, i.e. `WHERE enquiry.time_started != 0`

Comment: `Where ... and enquiry.time_started != 0`.

Comment: Hmmm.. but that condition is only needed for one particular count result and not for the whole query..

Comment: then just add it inside the count/sum calls. You can have arbitrary logic in there, and mysql will take the resulting true/false and cast it to int 0/1 for the sum/count purposes.